# Umbraco 8 create childnode on node created programmatically

Tags: umbraco8

How do I check if the node is new, I ONLY wish to create Components when I am saving a new node, Using Umbraco 8

ContentService.Saved += this.ContentService_Saved;

```
    private void ContentService_Saved(IContentService sender, ContentSavedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var node in e.SavedEntities)
        {
            if (node.ContentType.Alias == "basePage")
            {
                var childnode = sender.Create("Components", node.Id, "components");

                sender.Save(childnode, raiseEvents: false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Umbraco documentation for ContentService Events](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/events/contentservice-events#what-do-we-use-instead) happens to answer your specific question.  At the very bottom of the page,

> You can determine if an entity is brand new in either of those events.
>   In the Saving event - before the entity is persisted - you can check
>   the entity's HasIdentity property which will be 'false' if it is brand
>   new. In the Saved event you can [check to see if the entity 'remembers
>   being dirty'](https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/events/determining-new-entity)